# My android imageView is black no matter what

Tags: android, android-imageview

I try to display an ImageView into my app on a well (hopefully) defined view (XML)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activityShowLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#73C310"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ShowActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mainImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/moodButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:background="#000"
    android:src="@drawable/gs_04_pic" />

<!-- ... -->
```

and after that in my onCreate method on the activity

```java
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show);

    /* ... blabla bla ... */

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainImage);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(cream.getMedia(), 0, cream.getMedia().length);
    Drawable draw = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(draw);
    imageView.invalidate();
}
```

with cream.getMedia() returning a valid byte[] (from database)
which I can log giving me:

> 07-18 17:41:16.812: I/app(9883): byte[] is: [B@414af0b0

But at the end the imageView is black (no image on it)
If I don't run the onCreate code it displays the resource set in the XML (on black background as set in XML too)

What is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your byte array contains proper image data?

Comment: Are you sure `cream.getMedia()` gets an image correctly? The log just shows that yes, it's a byte array.

Comment: Also, instead of creating a `BitmapDrawable` and setting it into the ImaveView, try `imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap)`

Comment: Is your bitmap properly created after the decodeByteArray call ? can you log its size for example ?

Comment: Is it possible that your image (jpeg) is in CMYK?  Android will wont display cmyk images (your black is really blank).

Comment: @AleksG pretty much sure, it's a readfile from a PHP script. But I'll do more testing on this way. I did try imageView.setImageBitmap() gave me the same result.

Answer (score 6):

I run into this problem, in my case the problem came from the config in:

bluid.gradle

```
shrinkResources true
```

It deleted my files because I didn't have a static reference to my resources. (images in my case)

so I found this article "Keeping Resources" in this link [Resource Shrinking](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking)

In resumen it says: you should make a file in this path "/res/raw/keep.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:keep="@layout/l_used*_c,@layout/l_used_a,@layout/l_used_b*"/>
```

Comment: In my app, 4 of 7 images are disappear if I use `shrinkResources true`. But I don't get it to permit this. I've created keep.xml and put it to /android/app/src/main/res/raw (I'd to create this raw-directory). In there, I place the parameter for `tools:keep: @drawable/*.jpg`. But it doesn't work anyway. Any Idea why @Blaaz?

Comment: @suther, Its hard to tell without more context, but please check if you don't have a typo in your file, like the one in your comment. And try to use something like,
 tools:keep="@drawable/img_*" , its that the real location of the files? aren't they in the drawable-hdpi/ or another folder resolution? (for example)

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of you are trying to load a larger bitmap into the imageview, please try to scale it down before setting.